# How can I increase the numbers of posts on the main page of the Soho blogger/WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

The Soho theme has a section in which you can specify the number of blogs that show on the main page. I set it to 7 (the default number). But it only shows 3 under latest posts and then there is this older Posts link right below. How can I fix it so the 7 posts show on my main page?
*I have used google and have not found the answer to this problem.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider using the WordPress tag [tag:wordpress] on questions about WordPress, as that will increase your chances for an answer. This question might be more on topic at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as it has more to do with using a theme than it does with coding (as asked, it might turn into a coding answer).

Comment: apprpriate tags, shortened question, more detailed title

Answer (score 0):

For **Recent blog posts**

By default, three of your most recent blog posts are displayed on your home page. Under the Home page section of your theme editor, you can control how many posts are displayed (3, 6, 9) or disable them from being shown.

Per [Soho Theme Manual: Basic theme setup](https://support.pixelunion.net/hc/en-us/articles/360022239134-Soho-Theme-Manual)